# Karma runner exits on parse error while on TDD

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js, karma-runner

When TDDing with karma I can set it to continue executing when tests fails,
but if there is a parsing or syntax error with my javascript it will disconnect all browsers and shutdown,
requiring me to "karma start" again.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Run your code through [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) first.

For a full javascript TDD tooling setup check out the first several episodes at [lets code javascript](http://www.letscodejavascript.com/)